# Is it possible to read values from google sheets and replace certain text flags in google docs?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

Long story short, I need to dump a bunch of data from a sheet to a doc using flags like "(A12)" and such from a pre-determined spreadsheet. I have to do this every month from 4 to 8 times for my work and automating this would basically cut my workload in half.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google provides APIs for Sheets and Doc. For that need integration of these API with your App. Check the Google documentation for Sheet and doc you will get idea of how to integrate it. Then you will be able use APIs as per your requirement. By doing in logical order this is possible.

Read Cell values from google Sheet, check doc:
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values

Write that values to doc, check Google doc:
https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/move-text